# Characterization of homotopy equivalence: analogue to category theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

The fact that helped me really understand equivalences of categories is $$\mathscr{C} \simeq \mathscr{D} \iff \operatorname{sk}(\mathscr{C}) \cong \operatorname{sk}(\mathscr{D}).$$ Since homotopy equivalences between topological spaces $X,Y$ are quite similar to equivalences of categories, I'm wondering if there is a similar statement for topological spaces.

As a category lover I'm also inclined to ask: Is there even an analogue of $$ F:\mathscr{C} \simeq \mathscr{D} \iff F \text{ is fully faithful and essentially surjective}?$$

Comment: Topological spaces: sadly no. But Kan complexes: yes. Look up minimal Kan complexes.

Comment: It sort of depends what you're looking for. There's the unsatisfying tautological answer : yes, if you look at the homotopy category. For the second question, there's an $\infty$-categorical analogue