# Resemblance between equivalence of categories and homotopy equivalence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

Definitions of above mentioned equivalences look very much alike, though they speak about completely different things. I want to know whether this is a coincidence, or there is some kind of a more general construction inducing these definitions.

Thanks.

Comment: This question also reminds me of my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809169. (But those are different questions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a coincidence and can be made precise in two ways:

- In the [canonical model category structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat) on $\mathbf{Cat}$, equivalences of categories *are* weak equivalences. A good starting point for model categories are [these lecture notes](https://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Spalinski/theories.pdf) by Dwyer and Spalinsky.
- There is a [geometric realization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization+of+categories) functor $|-| : \mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Top}$. If $F,G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ are functors, then any natural transformation $F \to G$ induces a homotopy between the corresponding continuous maps $|F|,|G| : |C| \to |D|$. In particular, the geometric realization of an equivalence of categories (actually, any adjunction) is a homotopy equivalence.